# Local subdomains using Nginx and Docker Compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I want to test different subdomains locally, using `nginx` and `docker-compose`.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ...

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!

  ... 
  nginx:
    build: ./backend/nginx
    links:
      - phpmyadmin
    ports: 
      - "4000:80"
    volumes:
      - "./backend/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-phpmyadmin {
        server phpmyadmin:8081;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-phpmyadmin;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }

}
```

Nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

`etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 api.example.com
127.0.0.1 admin.example.com
```

When I run my `nginx` container and I navigate to `api.example.com:4000` on my browser I see a `502 Bad Gateway` page, and inside the container I get this message:

```
nginx_1       | 2019/07/27 12:17:00 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: api.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.4:8081/", host: "api.example.com:4000"
```

I guess that it should work using the port 80 instead of the 4000 but how can I test my configuration locally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing my upstream server port to 80:

```
upstream docker-phpmyadmin {
    server phpmyadmin;
}
```